# npviewer.bin no longer listed in the process list

Tags: flash, google-chrome, process

Since the most recent updates of Chrome, *npviewer.bin* is no longer listed in the process list when a flash content is loaded.

What process does Chrome use now?

** **EDIT** **

This is Google **Chrome** 17.0.963.56, and I usually

1. kill the process when it uses too much memory or
2. invoke `scanmem` on it to search for some values

Comment: (1) What were you trying to do with that process? (2) Are we talking about Chrome or Chromium? (3) Which version of chrome/chromium (tool menu button > about chromium)?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: Perhaps if you install the `nspluginwrapper` package it will start using it again. I'm not sure though. :)

Comment: And why would I do that? I usually follow the simple of rule of : "If it ain't broken or doesn't need maintenance/upgrade, don't touch it." It works fine now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npviewer.bin isn't part of Chrome - it's part of a compatibility wrapper called nspluginwrapper that makes it possible to use the 32-bit Flash plugin (and other 32-bit plugins as well) in a 64-bit browser. To 64-bit Chrome, nspluginwrapper "looks like" a 64-bit Flash plugin. But so does a real 64-bit Flash plugin, which is preferable, so I'd guess that you recently got such a plugin and thus Chrome is no longer using the nspluginwrapper version. Have you got a chrome --type=plugin process? It's been there the whole time, but with nspluginwrapper, it's just a proxy for the real plugin that runs in the npviewer.bin process. For a native 64-bit plugin, the plugin itself runs there.

Comment: oh! wonderful! indeed, there's a `--type=plugin --plugin-path=/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` process. Thanks!